# Django api throttle calling another server

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django as my web framework. I'm calling a third party API where they do throttling and I need to make sure I do not exceed the amount too many times or they will cancel my service.

How do I achieve this on the controller that I'm calling? I have my own API, such as `/ajax/getmydata/` and I'm making my API call in the controller. Is there a way to throttle my own calls?

Comment: I think you should move the api calling into a separate process. your app can call that process as frequently as possible, and requests will get queued up or discarded.

Comment: problem is that I need the result as a JSON data. I was hoping for a way to get it to either wait or ignore request.

Comment: I was looking into a way to have it call celery and wait for celery's response

Comment: As in, you want to poll celery to see if there is anything being worked on in the queue and then decide whether or not to make another API call based on that info?

Comment: No. I want to have some sort of queue mechanism that can handle the response but I want the controller to wait for the response and then submit for the request.